# def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): raise AttributeError("No constructor defined") AttributeError: No constructor defined

Tags: c++, python, wrapper, swig, gnuradio

I am trying to create a new DSP block in gnuradio using gr_modtool.py. gnuradio version is 3.3.0.
I have following code in abc.h file in include folder

```
 ifndef INCLUDED_ENERGYDETECTOR_LOCAL_SENSING_FF_H
 #define INCLUDED_ENERGYDETECTOR_LOCAL_SENSING_FF_H
 #include <gr_block.h>

 namespace gr {
   namespace energydetector {
 class ENERGYDETECTOR_API local_sensing_ff : virtual public gr_block
 {
  private:

  public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<local_sensing_ff> sptr;
    float d_pfa; int d_L; int d_samples;    
    static sptr make(float pfa=0.01,int L=16,int samples=1000);
    virtual void set_pfa(float input_a) { d_pfa = input_a; }  
    virtual int get_pfa() { return d_pfa; } 
    virtual void set_L(int input_b) { d_L = input_b; }  
    virtual int get_L() { return d_L; } 
    virtual void set_samples(int input_c) { d_samples = input_c; }  
   virtual int get_samples() { return d_samples; } 
     };
    } // namespace energydetector
  } // namespace gr
  #endif /* INCLUDED_ENERGYDETECTOR_LOCAL_SENSING_FF_H */
```

Implementation class for above header file is as:

```
 #ifndef INCLUDED_ENERGY-DETECTOR_LOCAL_SENSING_FF_IMPL_H
 #define INCLUDED_ENERGY-DETECTOR_LOCAL_SENSING_FF_IMPL_H

 #include <energy-detector/local_sensing_ff.h>

 namespace gr {
  namespace energydetector {
   class local_sensing_ff_impl : public local_sensing_ff
   {
   private:
      float d_pfa; int d_L; int d_samples;  
  public:
    local_sensing_ff_impl(float pfa,int L,int samples);
    ~local_sensing_ff_impl();
    void set_pfa(float input_a) { d_pfa = input_a; }  
    int get_pfa() { return d_pfa; } 
    void set_L(int input_b) { d_L = input_b; }  
    int get_L() { return d_L; } 
    void set_samples(int input_c) { d_samples = input_c; } 
    int get_samples() { return d_samples; }
        int general_work(int noutput_items,
           gr_vector_int &ninput_items,
           gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
           gr_vector_void_star &output_items);
   };
  } // namespace energy-detector
 } // namespace gr
#endif /* INCLUDED_ENERGY-DETECTOR_LOCAL_SENSING_FF_IMPL_H */
```

And SWIG file is abc.i as

```
 #define ENERGY_DETECTOR_API
 %include "gnuradio.i"          // the common stuff
 %include "energydetector_swig_doc.i"
 %{
    #include "energydetector/local_sensing_ff.h"
  %}

  %include "energydetector/local_sensing_ff.h"
  GR_SWIG_BLOCK_MAGIC2(energydetector, local_sensing_ff);
```

It build successfully but while executing I get following error :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): raise AttributeError("No constructor defined")
AttributeError: No constructor defined
```

Please help me out to debug this.

Comment: Show us the Python code too.

Comment: do you mean SWIG generated file

Comment: I actually don't know anything about that library, but when you "execute" your code you get a Python `AttributeError`, so it makes me think that you are writing Python and using this C++/Python hybrid library. Is this not the case?

Comment: Actually, disregard. I spent a little time looking to see if anyone else a similar problem to you and I realized that you are likely writing C++ instead. By the way, [this person](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2013-04/msg00267.html) had the same problem as you. He was advised to upgrade to 3.6.4, and he never got back to the thread to say whether or not it worked. But hey, check it out anyway.

Comment: Yeah I looked on that forum but there is no solution

Comment: Bummer. Although [this person](http://gnuradio.4.n7.nabble.com/gr-sync-block-AttributeError-No-constructor-defined-td36998.html) was writing Python instead, he was advised by a dev to upgrade as well. Try it?

Comment: By the way, the reason why you get that particular error is because one of the Python classes' constructors is nothing more than a `raise` statement, meaning it's not supposed to actually be constructed. Chances are you are trying to construct the wrong thing. What's `local_decision_fd` supposed to be? Again, bear with me as I don't know anything about this library (although I feel that I can deduce something useful here).

Comment: swig generated [file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4al7RUSNcjpdjZpbkVWbElHU00/edit?usp=sharing) and the file i used to execute the block is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4al7RUSNcjpMnJubERkUFprWjA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: sorry I typed wrong file name local_sensing_ff instead of local_sensing_fd

Comment: `local_sensing_ff` only defines class which will be called by other .cc file, so that other function can communicate with hardware. Have got the file I have shared.

Comment: Yeah, but I asked about `local_` *`decision`* `_fd`/`ff`.

Comment: apology but what do you want to know about local_sensing_ff.

Comment: No, **decision**. I don't see a definition for it, so it makes me wonder if you've been typing the wrong thing in your SWIG file.

Comment: I have edited the question that is typo error while posting question on SO , Since I was able to compile and install the code, there can't be error in .i file

Comment: Is it due to the absence of constructor in class (first block of code in above question). If I declare a constructor in that class then will that solve. If then how can i declare the constructor in class in first block of code

Comment: A wild guess here, but is it possible that `GR_SWIG_BLOCK_MAGIC2()` is trying to construct a `local_sensing_ff` when you should actually be constructing the concrete implementation, `local_sensing_ff_impl`? It likely compiles because you aren't referring directly to a method of that class, but just the class itself; thus, the compiler can't figure out in advance that you're going to try to construct a virtual class. I hope, of course, you wrote a header for your implementation as well so you can include that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i get to know that it was due to version not supported.
gr_modtool.py was only supported by GNURadio 3.6 or above.

Although we can build the block and use it in GRC but not sure why it can't work.
It must be the code structure that is generated by gr_modtool.py is not works with version 3.3.0

so anyone who came to this question make sure you have GNURadio 3.6 and above.
But if anyone has solved this either modifying gr_modtool.py or any code, then please let us know within this question.

Answer (score 0):

when I remove "from gnuradio.gr import *" from my code this problem goes away

Answer (score -1):

SWIG won't produce a constructor for a class that doesn't have a public constructor or is abstract.

See http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn9